# Separating Comma Demitted Values into Respective Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, delimiter, delimited

I have some data below and I am trying to figure out a way to separate some comma delimited values into their respective rows.

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBil9.png)

Initially I ran the following code which provided the delimited results for only two columns. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT ID, DATES ,VALUE
FROM TABLE
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (DATES,',')
```

I am wondering if there is a way to extrapolate the results from the code above into the other columns I posted in the screenshot. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I can provide